# How can we write the Splunk Query to find subField2 is present or not and if present get the counts of all subFiled2

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

{
index:"myIndex",
field1: "myfield1",
field2:  {"subField1":"mySubField1","subField2":145,"subField3":500},
...
..
.
}

SPL : index:"myIndex" eval result = if(field.subField2) .....
is the dot operator works in SPL ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your data is in JSON format. If so, you can use `spath` to extract fields from your structured data. Then just check if the field is present or not with `isnotnull`

```
index="myIndex" | spath | where isnotnull(field2.subField2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your data is in JSON format, this should do it:

```
index=myIndex sourcetype=srctp field2{}.subField2=*
```

If those are multivalue fields, you'll need to do an `mvexpand` first